# NetSuite Echosign Customization

Tags: netsuite, echosign

I'm new to Netsuite and Adobe EchoSign and coming from .NET background. My Client is a NetSuite cloud Customer and using Adobe Echosign App inside their forms.

Now, they want to change the behavior of Echosign. i.e., when the user clicks the 'Send For Signature' button, they want to take a different action in the next page like automatically sending the mail to customer based on some condition instead of clicking the 'Send For Signature' button again in the next page.

I would like to know.
1. What are my options here?
2. Should I get a Netsuite App developer license to make those modifications
3. Can I change anything realted to Adobe Echosign script code?

Any guidance will be helpful. I want to find whether I can handle this task.

Comment: Some app developer will lock the .js component file. Check first if the script can be modify and overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*1. What are my options here?*

I believe you will want to use SuiteScript to hide the default Send for Signature button and then write new code to create a new custom button to serve your purpose. That way you'll be overriding the default Send functionality. You'll create a script to display the button, and another to react to it being clicked.

*2. Should I get a Netsuite App developer license to make those modifications*

Yes and no. :) You will need to be granted login access on your Client's NetSuite account to develop and test these scripts. Ideally, they will have a sandbox account. If you do get a developer license, you could use your account for testing / learning so you don't mess up their NS account.

*3. Can I change anything realted to Adobe Echosign script code?*

No, it's a "managed" bundle and that would be bad practice even if you could. Instead, you will want to determine which of their SuiteScripts are called when their Send button is clicked, and then figure out how you can call the scripts from your script. I believe they have a script or two that handles all communication with their web service so that's your best bet.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the guidelines. My task is postponed for now, but definitely very useful pointers when I get a chance to work on Netsuite.  I tried for Netsuite App Developer licence, but NS is asking for actual company name, which I could not provide right now.